# gettimeofday(). is it agnostic for change in day light saving time?

Tags: unix

if the system time changes for day light saving time, does the output of gettimeofday() is changed?

Answer (score 1):

Note that Unix systems do not "change the system time" with daylight saving time -- it is *all* handled when programs want to print the current time, typically using `localtime(3)`.

The seconds since the epoch keep counting monotonically even when local governments decide to change the clocks on our walls.

Comment: thanks. does that mean if i change the system time while a program is running, the program invoking gettimeofday() periodically to do some bookkeeping/logic processing etc, will not be affected?

Comment: It should be fine ;) but I have to admit I've never thought to check around timeswitch time. Hehe.

Answer (score 1):

UNIX/linux computers use UNIX time which is more or less UTC i.e. Greenwich London. Only when you print or display the time does it get converted into localtime. This is done by consulting the TIMEZONE setting.

On linux the timezone database is in /usr/share/zoneinfo - the current timezone is defined in /etc/localtime. This file handles daylight savings time so the conversion when you print is handled cleanly. Note that the timezone is usually defined for geographical and political reasons.

Your timezone database will be periodically updated as various governments and/or local councils decide to change their timezone or daylight savings time settings. Recently Samoa skipped a complete day at the end of 2011. Provided the TIMEZONE files on any local Samoan UNIX/Linux computers had been updated beforehand then no problems would have been encountered.

Other considerations are NTP time synchronisation and leap seconds. If you run an NTP client to keep your computer in sync then this 'slews' the internal computer clock by either speeding it up or slowing it down - note that it is usually a *bad* idea to set the time manually using the 'date' or 'rdate'  commands as this can cause a jump in time and may affect software that uses timeouts of some kind. (A recent example was an Asterisk PABX that I had to maintain).

If you are going to change the time manually use the ntpdate command and define an upstream NTP server.